# loopback passport google hd param

Tags: loopbackjs, passport-google-oauth2

I am using a [loopback-component-passport](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-component-passport) to authenticate users via google OAuth2Strategy. Everything works well except passing the "[hd](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect)" or "hostedDomain" param to google.

My provider.json looks like this:

```
{
 "google-auth": {
 "provider": "google",
 "module": "passport-google-oauth",
 "strategy": "OAuth2Strategy",
 "clientID": "{clientID}",
 "clientSecret": "{clientSecret}",
 "callbackURL": "http://localhost:3000/auth/google/callback",
 "authPath": "/auth/google",
 "callbackPath": "/auth/google/callback",
 "successRedirect": "/auth/account",
 "scope": ["email", "profile"],
 "hd": "domain.tld",
 "link": false
 }
}
```

...but no "hd" param is passed to google :(.

I already tried the "hack" with "myClientSecret&hd=domain.tld" but all the values are url encoded before passing them and the characters "&" and "=" are therefore encoded and cause error...

dependencies in my package.json:

```
 "cls-hooked": "^4.2.2",
 "compression": "^1.0.3",
 "cors": "^2.5.2",
 "helmet": "^3.12.0",
 "loopback": "^3.0.0",
 "loopback-boot": "^2.27.1",
 "loopback-component-access-groups": "^1.2.0",
 "loopback-component-explorer": "^5.0.0",
 "loopback-component-passport": "^3.6.0",
 "loopback-context": "^3.3.0",
 "passport-google-oauth": "^1.0.0",
 "serve-favicon": "^2.0.1",
 "strong-error-handler": "^2.3.2"
```

Anyone has some experiences with this? Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding:

```
"authOptions": {
    "hd": "domain.tld"
}
```

More info: http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Configuring-providers.json.html#oauth-2